# Charles proxy and missing hits

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

I have a very strange issue and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what could be done to prevent it.

I'm using charles proxy to debug what my android application is sending over the internet. It worked fine on my samsung galaxy s3 but some trouble arrived when I changed the testing phone.

I have a test that sends 30 http get on a remote server and charles is in the middle to check and log.

- With my s3 everything is fine.
- With my one plus one, my server is seeing those 30 hits, but charles is only seeing about 15 (it's variable between 15 and 18 -_-)
- My a galaxy tab, we have the same issue as with the one plus one.
- If using Fiddler the results are better, but not always 100% correct either. (but still 100% working on my s3)

Those phones have a different SDK:
- s3 is in 4.3
- one plus one is cyanogen 4.4.4
- galaxy tab is 4.4.2

So I'm looking for a sure way to debug all this. It's really blocking for us ;(

I tried adding some random to the url of the request to avoid anyone from dropping the hit as "too similar to another one" but didn't change anything.

I also tried phone->fiddler->charles->internet. Same as with charles alone and if I close Charles, then fiddles works correctly and find all the hits again.

Has anyone witnessed anything similar?

Comment: How are you setting the proxy? Via Wi-Fi --> Modify connection --> Proxy or programmatically?

Comment: With wifi, modify connection -> advanced options -> manual proxy

Comment: In my experience, that option is not 100% reliable. I would suggest using the `java.net.Proxy` and `java.net.ProxySelector` classes and set the proxy address programmatically.

Comment: I'll post an answer in the meantime.

Comment: Is there any solution to stop charles to detect my apps http requests ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Completely filtering https? It's quite easy to filter anything so you should be able to only see what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, using the Wi-Fi configuration options **is not a 100% reliable solution**.

I would suggest using the [`java.net.Proxy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Proxy.html) and [`java.net.ProxySelector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ProxySelector.html) classes and set the proxy address programmatically. This way you can be sure that your app is honoring the proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks! It's indeed working properly when setting up the proxy programmatically!!! I find it quite strange that proxy on wifi is not working 100%, when I check the devices tested it seems the issue is appearing starting 4.4 is it something android changed?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to take not of now is that starting Android 24 we need to add some configuration to trust the proxy.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html

Comment: What if you don't own the app you're reverse engineering?

Comment: At best you can use an older phone or an iPhone if the app is on both platform. Otherwise, nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: What about unpinning the SSL?